# IPhone 6s Apps are not being shown in iTunes on Windows 10

Tags: itunes, windows, iphone

I have a problem since i installed windows 10, i own an IPhone 6s and on iTunes  Apps are not being shown in the apps tab (I mean the box on the left side where apps and its size are listed, it is just blank as if they were undetected although they are shown on the tabs on the right)

I know this only happens on Windows 10 as i have a Laptop with Windows 7 and it is working properly with the same iTunes version.

This is driving me crazy because sometimes i need to clear some space and do not know which apps to remove apart from guessing ...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

If all you're wanting to do is clear space on your iPhone and you want to know how much space each app takes up, you can do this all directly from your iPhone as follows:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Swipe up and tap on **General**
3. Tap on *Storage & iCloud Usage*
4. Under the Storage heading (not the iCloud heading), tap on *Manage Storage*
5. Give your iPhone a little time to calculate how much space each of your apps is taking up
6. When finished they'll al be listed from largest to smallest

Now you can tap on any 3rd party app to see a breakdown of its data usage or to actually delete the app altogether.

In the case of Apple's iOS apps, tapping on them will give you various options depending on the app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but yes that is how i have been managing space, the only option availble on most if not all is just to delete the app

Comment: Due to the nature of my work i am constantly syncing photos from the iphone to the PC and really it would be easier for me to control from within the iTunes and not from the phone itself as it is kind of time consuming ... Do you know if it is possible to have this feature working on Windows 10?